# What happens when a non-token creature loses all abilities, is exiled, then returns?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So I was playing with some friends and we ran into a problem. My opponent had a creature with both hexproof and indestructible.

I drew and played [Polymorphist's Jest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383351). I then attacked with my creature, which had [Voidwalk](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Voidwalk) encoded on it. It wasn't blocked, so I cast Voidwalk with his currently blue frog creature as the target and exiled it. Now, I know exiled tokens immediately die or cease to exist, but what would happen to his creature? Would it return or simply be gone?

Comment: How is your Voidwalk encoded on your opponent's creature? The cipher ability only allows you to encode the spell on a creature you control. (Plus the triggered ability from cipher is on the creature and would be removed by Polymorphist's Jest.)

Comment: @HaoYe There are two creatures - the OP has one with Voidwalk encoded already, and their opponent has the one that's been turned into a frog.

Comment: @Jefromi Ah, got it. Parsing error on my part.

Comment: The rewrites to the question, to gloss over the confusion of the OP around tokens and Polymorphist's Jest render the otherwise very good answer of esoterik rather confusing.

Comment: @John The question does still mention tokens, just not the title. It's pretty confusing to future readers if the title talks about exiling tokens when the question isn't ultimately about that at all.

Comment: Remember the logic of MTG is Boolean. If a card creates token it will say so. A card only does what its card text / oracle wording tells you. Nothing more, nothing less

Answer (score 11):

[Polymorphist's Jest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383351) does **not** create tokens, it only changes the stats and characteristics of the creature's controlled by the targeted player. It is still the same game object as far as Magic is concerned.

Under the circumstances presented in your question, your opponent's creature would be 'flickered' (magic slang for exiled and then returned to the battlefield) and when it returned it wouldn't be a 1/1 frog anymore, it would be whatever the face up of whatever card was returned.

Comment: Note that Voidwalk only returns the creature to the battlefield in the end step, not immediately, so it's not quite traditional flickering. (Of course this doesn't affect the main point of the answer.)